# Can entries be disabled by default for 2/3 of the languages on my website

Tags: multi-environment, language, saveentry

I have a 3 language website that I made for a client.
The website is in Dutch, Japanese and English.

When my clients creates a new entry, most of the time they want to have the Japanese and English version disabled and only show the Dutch version. After they have created the entry they have to manually disable the Japanese and English version.

Is it possible to have the Japanese and English version disabled by default?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to have the Japanese and English version disabled by default?

Yes. Visit *Settings -> Sections -> [Your Section Name]* inside the Control Panel.

Under the heading `Which locales should entries in this section target?` there's a `Default Entry Status` Lightswitch for each locale. Make sure the Lightswitches are *off* (i.e., not green) for the English and Japanese locales, and you're all set.

Obviously, you'll need to do this for any and all sections targeting the 3 locales – there's no "global" setting for it.